# Getting CMake CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG to work

Tags: cmake

Note: This is my first time using CMake.  I don't know much about it, so I'm just posting a bunch of information to see if anyone can see my problem.

I would like the ability to automatically determine which c++11 flag is appropriate, given my compiler.  There are many examples of this line.  Here is my CMakeLists.txt following such an example:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

#Add the c++11 flag, whatever it is
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG(-std=c++11 COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG(-std=c++0x COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
else()
  message(STATUS "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++11 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif()

project(AnalyzeGames)
set(AnalyzeGames_SRCS AnalyzeGames.cpp)
add_executable(AnalyzeGames ${AnalyzeGames_SRCS})
```

Here is my cmake output when trying to use this file: http://pastebin.com/3AUwqffD

Here is CMakeError.log: http://pastebin.com/EbNKvGt8

Here is CMakeOutput.log: http://pastebin.com/kVJ0enJC

`echo $CC`: /usr/bin/gcc

`echo $CXX`: /usr/bin/g++

I can compile a simple test executable with g++ using either flag manually.

`cmake --version`: cmake version 2.8.12.2

For some reason CMake is not recognizing that my compiler does support both of those flags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cmake output tells you that it does not recognize the '.cxx' extension because it doesn't know that your project is a C++ project. To fix this, you should enable C++ in the [project](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/project.html) command. Try to change the following line:

```
project(AnalyzeGames)
```

to:

```
project(AnalyzeGames CXX)
```

and then move it to the 2nd line of the CMakeLists.txt, right under `cmake_minimum_required`. The configuration should work as expected after this.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**

Compiler checks are only performed in the variable passed is not previously defined, which includes in the cache from previous failed attempts.  Use `unset(my_var CACHE)` to force checking to always occur, or just be aware of this behaviour and clear the cache manually when needed.

**Detail**

I too had this problem (with `cmake` 2.8.12.2) and I had to turn on trace output, and step through the code to get a similar toy build to work I had make sure the variables I used (`COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11_*`) in these calls:

```
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG(-std=c++11 COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG(-std=c++0x COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
```

Were set such that they named themselves:

```
set(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11 "COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11")
```

The other posters solution didn't work for me, it mainly just seemed to limit the detecting of compilers to just CXX and ignored the C compiler.

The issue appears to be with this line of code in the cmake module:

```
if("${VAR}" MATCHES "^${VAR}$")
```

Which in the trace output is:

```
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/CheckCXXSourceCompiles.cmake(30):  if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X MATCHES ^COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X$ )
```

It looks as if the expression on the left of the `MATCHES` is replaced with the variables value, but the expression on the right is assumed to be plain text.

If the `MATCH` fails then the main part of the macro is skipped and according the to the log the check fails.

Looking at later versions of this macro online it looks as if this line has changed to only perform the compile check if the variable is undefined.

It as at this point that I realise that this is the intent / hack of the original code; if the X is undefined then `"X" MATCHES "^X$"` will be true, but then the compile check can be performed, fail for some other reason and then never be performed again.

So the solution is either force unset of variable in cache before calling the macro using:

```
 unset(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X CACHE)
```

Or clear the cache manually and be prepared for this behaviour.